# UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs) adds junk to parameter values

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

Here is my code snippet:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    
String urlStr = FolderManager.ApplicationUnderTestUrl();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlStr);   
List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(1);

if ((paramName != null ) && (paramVal != null))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) 
    {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(paramName[i], paramVal[i]));
    }
}
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs ,"UTF-8"));      
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);       
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

The above code adds some + (plus) signs to my parameter values wherever a ' '(space) is encountered. How can I avoid this?

Comment: That's perfectly normal, encoding url would result into that behavior. I would suggest you to encode manually the stuff that you want in your own way.

Comment: Is there no other way to do it? My code has a lot of different requests and the parameter description has been done in this way. Can I use some other technique to sort this out?

Comment: The `+` gets decoded to a space again.

Comment: @JoopEggen can you please explain how?

Comment: Over HTTP; URL encoding is for HTTP transfer, if one need to do it oneself [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) is the pendant of URLEncoder.